# Private Key from Extended Private Key and Public Address

Tags: public-key, cryptocurrency

Is it possible to generate a private key from a public address and an extended private key?

For context: I am using C# and NBitcoin. The public address is generated from the outside via an extended public key and I have access to the mnemonic, extended private key, seed, etc.

Comment: The question was closed because it's vague in a cryptographic context: the notions of "public address" and "extended private key" have no definition in cryptography. They may have in some particular cryptocurrency, but specifications of a particular cryptocurrency are off-topic. The question could be reopened if it defined the terms it uses (and asked for an algorithm rather than code suitable for a stated language). Alternatively, it could be asked in a website dedicated to the cryptocurrency, e.g. if that's bitcoin at [bitcoin-SE](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com).